# Determine if a Handlebars helper was called as a block instead of inline

Tags: ember.js

I've got a helper that I would like to take both inline and blocks. I just need to determine if a block was passed to see what it should do. I don't see anything in the scope of the registered helper function that seems to help.

Comment: Can you explain more about what you want the helper to do

Comment: I don't see believe that is relevant in this case. I am simply looking for a way to setup an if/else statement in the helper depending upon if the helper was called as a block.

Answer (score 2):

Checking to see if `fn` exists on `options` will tell if a block is passed:

```
!!(options.fn)
```